# What exactly is utils.h in c?

Tags: c

I see many programmers that include "utils.h" to their program.
Tried to search for what it is exactly and what is the proper use of utils.h, but all I found was different versions of the file.
So what is it exactly?

Comment: It is just a short version of `#include "cant-think-of-a-better-name.h"`

Comment: Iit's just a name, like include "common.h" or whatever name you can use for your file and unused by standard libraries.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many programmers define common functionalities in **utils.c** and declare them in **utils.h** . You could implement for example command line parsing methods in utils.h / utils.c.

But utils.h is no standard file to be included.

Answer (score 4):

The `"` mark instead of `<` mark in `#include "utils.h"` is a bit of a clue.  If it had been

```
#include <utils.h>
```

then would be likely that `utils.h` is a general utility header.  But being `#include "abc"` means it is specific to the project and `utils.h` is likely in the same folder as other source files for the project.

Most likely `utils.h` is VERY project-specific and contains helper functions for the project.

Comment: Nice answers here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename) about #include <filename> vs #include "filename".